# Finding an element and clicking on it using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am making a script that will navigate through a website and perform some actions for me. But I am stuck trying to make my script click on the following elemnt:

```
<a href="JavaScript:OnCopy(22291488);" title="Copy Trip"><img src="../Images/copy.gif"></a>
```

As there is no ID or class name for this element, i tried to find the element by xpath and clicking on it by using the following code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
```

....

```
copy = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="divGrid"]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/span/a[2]')
copy.click()
```

This isn't working, so I am open to suggestions to how to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you supply more of your code and the url with the element you're trying to click on?

Comment: also provide code where you instantiate your driver.

Comment: //a[contains(@href, "OnCopy(22291488)")]

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Copy Trip']>img[src$='/Images/copy.gif']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Copy Trip' and contains(@href, 'OnCopy')]/img[contains(@src, '/Images/copy.gif')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```